# How to continue communication on a VoIP call with the user playing another application's music in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, call, voip

I am running the VoIP application using the pjsip library. Everything is working fine in the foreground. Suppose my call is established, the application goes to background, and we have good communication between all end users. If any end user then plays some music from another application, their communication is lost from the VoIP call. I would like the communication to continue even if another application's music plays. Skype handles this scenario very nicely.

I have checked so many forums, but I couldn't found any solution for this. Could anyone suggest how I can resolve this?